# JavaFx App on 64 bit Win 7 platform

Tags: netbeans, 64-bit, javafx, java

I wrote a JavaFx app (JavaFx windows based form) on my desktop running

1. Win 7 32 Bit
2. Netbeans 7.3 Beta
3. jdk-7u9-windows-i586

and it runs successfully.

I recently got a laptop running

1. Win 7 64 Bit
2. Netbeans 7.3 Beta
3. jdk-7u9-windows-x64

I just copied the code over and switch the Java Platform.... currently its set to the default "Default JavaFx Platform".

If i run the app I get the following error dialog

JavaFx launcher error - Exception while running Application

Anyone know what I need to change here...

Full stack trace when running application

```
ant -f "C:\\DEV\\Projects\\Java Apps\\BaseAppPlatform" jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\DEV\Projects\Java Apps\BaseAppPlatform\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\DEV\Projects\Java Apps\BaseAppPlatform\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.2
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Signing JAR: C:\DEV\Projects\Java Apps\BaseAppPlatform\dist\BaseAppPlatform.jar to C:\DEV\Projects\Java Apps\BaseAppPlatform\dist\BaseAppPlatform.jar as nb-jfx

Warning: 
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
Enter Passphrase for keystore: Enter key password for nb-jfx: 
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib\ant-javafx.jar
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 12 files to C:\DEV\Projects\Java Apps\BaseAppPlatform\dist\run858846669
jfx-project-run:
Executing com.javafx.main.Main from C:\DEV\Projects\Java Apps\BaseAppPlatform\dist\run858846669\BaseAppPlatform.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09/bin/java
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.za.chrispie.LoginController
file:/C:/DEV/Projects/Java%20Apps/BaseAppPlatform/dist/run858846669/BaseAppPlatform.jar!/BaseAppPlatform/Login.fxml:9
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:728)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:777)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:182)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:565)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2314)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2742)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2721)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2694)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2683)
at BaseAppPlatform.BaseAppPlatform.start(BaseAppPlatform.java:21)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.za.chrispie.LoginController
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:728)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:777)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:182)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:565)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2314)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2742)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2721)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2694)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2683)
at BaseAppPlatform.BaseAppPlatform.start(BaseAppPlatform.java:21)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.za.chrispie.LoginController
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:726)
... 19 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.za.chrispie.LoginController` you missed few code or dependent library while copying.

Find java or jar file responsible for class `co.za.chrispie.LoginController` and make sure:

- it exists on your laptop
- it's in the correct location package-wise
- it's included into your new project (sources folder)